# Symfony DOMCrawler: How to change html?

Tags: php, symfony

How to edit html of elements? I tried this, but i get this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Attaching DOM nodes
>   from multiple documents in the same crawler is forbidden.

```
$crawler = new Crawler('<h1>The title</h1>');
$crawler
    ->filter('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6')
    ->each(function (Crawler $crawler, $i) use (&$replace) {
        $crawler->html('<span>test</span>' . $crawler->html());
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$crawler = new Crawler($doc);

$crawler
    ->filter('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6')
    ->each(function (Crawler $crawler) use ($doc) {
        foreach ($crawler as $node) {
            $span = $doc->createElement('span', 'test');
            $node->parentNode->insertBefore($span, $node);
        }
    });
```

> **Important:** Use *same* `DOMDocument` object for creating new tag that used in `Crawler` object.

As explained in [The DomCrawler Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) docs:

> An instance of the Crawler represents a set of DOMElement objects, which are nodes that can be traversed...

So, you need to traverse `Crawler` object before manipulate `DOMElements`.

Comment: textContent changes only text, not html. Sorry i edited question.